# JConsole/JVisualVm Empty Menu while connecting a remote machine

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole, jvisualvm

I have a java app running on serverA with port 1337. I can telnet the remote server with that port and telnet connection seems okay. But when I try to connect from my machine by using either JConsole or JVisualVm, I got nothing but a blank white screen for both.

The screenshot is here:

[image: The screenshot]

When I try other remote machines there is no problem at all, and for serverA, it shows nothing, and nothing on the command line about what was possibly going wrong.

any ideas about solving this?

EDIT:

Commandline options that I use are

```
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=true \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1337 \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=./config/jmxremote.password \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=./config/jmxremote.access \
```

EDIT2:

```
Sep 17, 2013 10:59:13 AM RMIConnector connect
FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: rmiServer=RMIServerImpl_Stub[UnicastRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[remotehost:44457,javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory@20c449e3](remote),objID:[2ea1fcfa:1400abe0c89:-7fff, -6056681295086157153]]]]] connecting...
Sep 17, 2013 10:59:13 AM RMIConnector connect
FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: rmiServer=RMIServerImpl_Stub[UnicastRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[remotehost:44457,javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory@20c449e3](remote),objID:[2ea1fcfa:1400abe0c89:-7fff, -6056681295086157153]]]]] finding stub...
Sep 17, 2013 10:59:13 AM RMIConnector connect
FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: rmiServer=RMIServerImpl_Stub[UnicastRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[remotehost:44457,javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory@20c449e3](remote),objID:[2ea1fcfa:1400abe0c89:-7fff, -6056681295086157153]]]]] connecting stub...
Sep 17, 2013 10:59:13 AM RMIConnector connect
FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: rmiServer=RMIServerImpl_Stub[UnicastRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[remotehost:44457,javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory@20c449e3](remote),objID:[2ea1fcfa:1400abe0c89:-7fff, -6056681295086157153]]]]] getting connection...
Sep 17, 2013 11:00:27 AM RMIConnector connect
FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: rmiServer=RMIServerImpl_Stub[UnicastRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[remotehost:44457,javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory@20c449e3](remote),objID:[2ea1fcfa:1400abe0c89:-7fff, -6056681295086157153]]]]] failed to connect: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: remotehost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
Sep 17, 2013 11:00:27 AM RMIConnector close
FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: rmiServer=RMIServerImpl_Stub[UnicastRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[remotehost:44457,javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory@20c449e3](remote),objID:[2ea1fcfa:1400abe0c89:-7fff, -6056681295086157153]]]]] closing.
```

Comment: The problem description is pretty ambiguous. The port 1337 is a port where the JMX connector listens or is it a custom application port? Do you have the default platform MBean server enabled on the application JVM? What is the connection string used to connect to the application's MBean server?

Comment: not quite sure what you mean about MBean server, but I am using java commandline options to start the port

Comment: can you add the command line options you use to the problem description?

Comment: @JB i have added those

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the problem but no luck. I either setup the passwords and SSL correctly and can connect or the connection is refused at all.

I would recommend, as the next step, run jvisualvm and take a look at the log file - you can find it under Help/About/Logfile
Also, the screen in jvisualvm shouldn't be blank - it should display  at least some info. Can you take a thread dump of jvisualvm with the blank screen and attach it here along with the log?

Comment: i have added the logs, seems like there is a timeout though dont understand why i am getting that... by the way, after removing the credential check from the process, jconsole/jvisualvm is able to connect without any problems to the remotehost without any problems

Comment: "Connection refused to host: remotehost" looks pretty suspicious. Is the "remotehost" a valid host name of your serverA? If not, try adding  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<serverA IP> to the command line options.

Comment: i have actually used the ip addresses for that... to keep it simple i gave a name while posting here..
i am able to access it without username/password with exactly the same settings. still trying to figure out the root reason though